# Group Pandas dataframe by one column, drop rows based on another column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, pandas-groupby

I have a pandas dataframe which looks like this:

```
     UNIT        MACHINE
1    a100        001
2    a100        002
3    a100        003
4    a100        001
5    b222        001
6    b222        002
7    b222        002
8    b222        003
```

I would like to group it based on "UNIT" and drop the rows that do not have the [001, 002, 003] "MACHINE" sequence. That means because UNIT "a100" has the sequence [001, 002, 003, 001], it should be dropped, but the UNIT "b222" remains, because the sequence is right regardless of repetition of MACHINE 002.

The output should look like this:

```
     UNIT        MACHINE
5    b222        001
6    b222        002
7    b222        002
8    b222        003
```

The sequence [001, 002, 003] is one of the acceptable MACHINE sequences which I have written here as an example. There are several of such sequences, all of which are monotonically increasing.

How should I combine GroupBy and drop to perform this?

Comment: How does the expected output look like? And your part of the code?

Comment: I added the output above. Unfortunately  I have no code for this.

Comment: Try yourself once you might get the solution by yourself. If you get into any problem then SO will be glad to help.

Comment: I've been trying for 2 days, I could not get it right :)

Comment: @sepideh, currently it's not very clear to me. Is it sufficient to drop a group if its last `MACHINE != '003'`? What should happen to a group if it ends with '003' but one of other statuses is missing? What should we do with a group containing MACHINEs in the following order: `[`002`, '001', '003']?

Comment: The order and the number of MACHINEs are important. It should always be [001, 002, 003]. If a MACHINE value is missing for a UNIT, then that UNIT should be dropped. For example this is acceptable: [001, 001, 002,002,002,003,003]. But this is not: [001,003]

Comment: @MaxU I think OP just wants a non-decreasing sequence of MACHINE IDs, I suppose.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ, thanks for clarification!

Comment: @sepideh, unfortunately only one answer can be accepted - so you would need to choose one, which fits you better ;-)

Comment: Thank you everyone, the problem is solved with @COLDSPEED 's solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
In [26]: chk_set = set(df.MACHINE.unique())

In [27]: df[df.groupby('UNIT')['MACHINE']
              .transform(lambda x: x.is_monotonic_increasing & chk_set.issubset(set(x)))]
Out[27]:
   UNIT MACHINE
5  b222     001
6  b222     002
7  b222     002
8  b222     003
```

**UPDATE:**

assuming you have the following DF:

```
In [90]: df
Out[90]:
    UNIT MACHINE
1   a100     001
2   a100     002
3   a100     003
4   a100     001
5   b222     001
6   b222     002
7   b222     002
8   b222     003
9     c1     001
10    c1     003
11    c2     078
12    c2     079
13    c2     080
14    c3     078
16    c3     080
```

and an array of **concatenated** groups to check against:

```
In [91]: chk_groups = np.array(['001002003','078079080'])
```

Solution:

```
In [92]: df[df.groupby('UNIT')['MACHINE']
              .transform(lambda x: x.is_monotonic_increasing
                                   & np.in1d(x.unique().sum(),chk_groups))]
Out[92]:
    UNIT MACHINE
5   b222     001
6   b222     002
7   b222     002
8   b222     003
11    c2     078
12    c2     079
13    c2     080
```

Comment: This solution functions quit well. The only thing is that I need to define the chk_set manually, which makes generalizing the solution a bit difficult.

Comment: @sepideh, would this help: `chk_set = set(df.MACHINE.unique())` ?

Comment: MaxU this might be the perfect solution.

Comment: @MaxU the thing is that there are different acceptable MACHINE orders in the same dataframe. To be precise, if the MACHINE sort is either [001, 002, 003] or [078, 079,080] it is acceptable. If I define a set at the beginning, then I have to find all of these acceptable MACHINE orders.

Comment: @sepideh, it would be very helpful if your question would contain those edge-cases...

Comment: @MaxU thank you very much for your hints. I am very new to Stack Overflow and your hints help me a lot.

Answer (score 4):

Use `diff` + `groupby` + `transform` with `all`.

```
m = df.MACHINE\
      .astype(int)\
      .diff()\
      .fillna(0)\
      .isin([0, 1])\
      .groupby(df.UNIT)\
      .transform('all')

m

1    False
2    False
3    False
4    False
5     True
6     True
7     True
8     True
Name: MACHINE, dtype: bool
```

Use `diff` + `isin` to detect whether rows are non-decreasing or not (only steps of 0 or 1 are considered valid).

Next, using `m`, index into `df`.

```
df[m]

   UNIT MACHINE
5  b222     001
6  b222     002
7  b222     002
8  b222     003
```

Comment: @Dark I did not really pay attention to the comments that much. I apologise for that.

Comment: check once with all the values as 001 for any one group

Comment: @Dark I convert the ID to integers, so it's not a problem.

Comment: No im not talking about ints. Try once. Instead of different values all of them same value.

Comment: @Dark Oh, I get you now. The idea is to have the sequence, my function is only checking monotonicity, so it isn't a perfect one!

Answer (score 4):

You can do :

```
 df.groupby('UNIT')['MACHINE'].transform(lambda x : (x.astype(int).diff().fillna(0) >= 0).all())     
df[sample]

   UNIT  MACHINE
5  b222        1
6  b222        2
7  b222        2
8  b222        3
```

Comment: Good one, quite succinct.

Comment: It was in my kernel from last 30 mins. I wonder why I din't post the solution

Comment: I like this solution, but i'm not sure that it covers this case: `['001','003']` PS upvoted in a hope that it will be fixed ;-)...

Comment: MaxU perhaps its should be != 1, rather than less than 0 . Fixed .

Comment: @MaxU the question was matching the pattern right? [001, 002, 003] . I thought it should have the maximum diffference of 1. I should take a look now. Will surely update

Comment: @Dark, i think the diff should be either `0` or `1`, if its `2` then there was a jum from `001` to `003` and `002` is missing